# I want to combine a hub and spoke VPN with a dialup VPN

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, vpn, juniper, srx

Can I do this with a Juniper SRX-100?

I have a combination of corporate office users and remote work from home users.  A total of around 30 users with 10 remote work from home.  The remote users run a mixture of Windows, Mac OSX and Linux (Ubuntu and Centos).  It would be nice if the built-in/native VPN clients can be used to connect.  It would also be nice if the VPN client for the Apple iPhone/iPad would work, but it's not a show stopper.

I have three sites that the corporate office and remote work from home users need to access.  Two of the sites use Cisco ASA devices, and one uses a Juniper SSG5.  These three sites are not under my control, they are our customers.  We may have more customers in the future with site to site VPN requirements.

I'm thinking a hub and spoke VPN config with site to site VPNs would work.

How do I setup the remote work from home dialup VPN to have access to the three site to site VPNs?

Comment: This is a super old post, but in case someone has the same question... For the corporate offices, I will assume that they have static WAN IPs, which in this case a site-to-site VPN would be a good way to go with little headaches. Otherwise, if you must, then you could go for the dynamic VPN feature, but you will need to make sure you have the proper licenses for that (per client).